# Passing a value from a JFrame to a JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have an annoying problem using JFrames and JPanels. I have a class extending a JFrame and in the contructor I have a string. I want to pass this value into the JPanel also in the contructor. I cant think how to do it. This is what I did:

```
  public class NewFileMaker extends JFrame{

private String name;

public NewFileMaker(JPanel j, String newfilename){
    setTitle("New File");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.add(j);
    this.pack();
    this.name = newfilename;



}
```

Is there a way of passing the value "name"? I could extend JPanel and create a new class and a new method, but it would require a lot of reworking a lot of other classes.

MORE INFO:
I took the advice and extended JPanel, which was actually really painless.

The NewFileMaker class is called in another class like this

```
new NewFileMaker(new GeneratePanel(getFileName()));
```

where getfileName() gets the name I wanted. Actually the solution is so simple I have to apologize to everybody. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: What should the JPanel do with this String (name) ?

Comment: As Bogdan said it depends on what you are going to do with this string

Comment: Various things, but mainly creates a text file with the name as the title and uses the name in various places within the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the best solution would be extending jpanel.
Anyway if you can't do that maybe you can add to jframe a PropertyChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

JPanel doesn't have a string constructor, so you can't pass it in that way.

You can try calling `panel.setName(name)` instead.

Comment: I'm trying that now. j.setName(name), and inside the Panel this.getName(), but it keep returning null.

Comment: @JJG What do you mean "inside" the panel? Please show us some code